# multiple threads not working properly

Tags: python, multithreading, audio-recording

I want to create two threads, so when I run the program, the 1st thread activates the function "recorder" to record audio, and after 5 seconds it stops and 2nd thread activates to do some activity. After n second thread2 stops and thread1 comes back in position. This process continues until we terminate it by using keyboard exception.

I have following code. It starts with recording the audio, saves it but 2nd thread doesn't seem to work as the program finishes with exit code 0.
Can someone correct me where I have made a mistake? Thanks

```
from threading import  Thread
import time
from time import ctime
import pyaudio
import wave

def recorder(name, delay, repeat):
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 2
    RATE = 44100
    CHUNK = 1024
    RECORD_SECONDS = 3
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"

    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # start Recording
    stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE, input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
    print("recording...")
    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
    print("finished recording")

    # stop Recording
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()

    waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
    waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
    waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    waveFile.close()

def save(name, delay, repeat):
    print("Saved")

def Main():
    t1 = Thread(target=recorder, args=("Timer1", 1, 5))
    t2 = Thread(target=save, args=("Timer2", 5, 5))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    print("Main complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: You are not waiting for your threads to complete. I assume you need `t1.join() t2.join()`

Comment: Where do I have to add these? After t1.start() & t2.start respectively?

Comment: Read about [condition-objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#condition-objects)

Comment: you don't need thread, thread is used for parallelism.and your problem need schedule.